# Xamarin iOS app Opens the immediately crashes after Launch Screen

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and deploying to a physical device via the Xamarin Mac Agent (Xcode 8.3, Xamarin Studio 6.3). My completed project was working fine a couple of months ago. I was requested to make a small change to the application and VS wouldn't connect to the Mac Agent. I upgraded Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio. At that point, the Mac agent was able to connect (One obvious change I noticed is how VS handles assets). But it was at this point that when I tried to run the application, it would open, show the launchscreen and then immediately close.  Going to xCode -> Window -> Devices and inspecting the Device Log doesn't really help since memory addresses are only given in regards to the thread that crashed. For example:

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
x0: 0x00000000000000...

There is nothing that resembles a reader friendly stacktrace. Also, the entry point method is never reached in VS (e.g. AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching).

Thanks in advance.